# use of fixedSIze in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

i have made a View extension to make fixedSize more flexible.

Here it is.

It works fine, but i am not sure whether there is an easier way to implement this...?

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct FixedSizeView<Content> : View where Content : View {
    var content: Content
    var on: Bool
    public init(_ on: Bool, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self.on = on
    }

    var body : some View {
        Group {
            if on {
                content.fixedSize()
            } else {
                content
            }
        }
    }
}


@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension View {
    func fixedSize(active: Bool) -> FixedSizeView<Self> {
        FixedSizeView(active) {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't make it simpler, as this

```
extension View {
    func fixedSize(active: Bool) -> some View {
        Group {
            if active {
                self.fixedSize()
            } else {
                self
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

Comment: i tried it in this way, but was too silly to get it working, so i came up to the complicated way.... ;) that's why i was asking. Thank you!